# Allow increasing the font size for the downloadable versions of a Developer Story

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs, developer-story

Is there a way to increase the font of the developer story while downloading the story in the traditional format?

Note that the font size in the generated PDF file is pretty small and makes it hard to read.

Please find a way to solve this issue or there is no point of downloading the developer story if it is not usable.

It is also better if it can be downloaded in a doc format too.

Comment: 1/. May we have example for the too small police from someone with actual information in the Developer Story? 2/. PDF, is The Portable Document Format. The name suggest it a good format for sending a resume. If this is part of the Feature Request I may need a post on it's own with a list of Pros. Something that justify the devlopement time needed.

Comment: What do you mean by *"doc format"*? .docx / .doc ([Microsoft Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word))? Or something else?